# Why Sonata No. 16 K. 545 by Mozart is told to be done in C Major

Tags: scales, mozart

I have seen an analysis of Sonata No. 16  K. 545 by Mozart here:

https://www.libertyparkmusic.com/discover-key-music-part-1/image-2-highlights-and-circles-sonata-no-16-in-c-major-k-545/

May I know why the sonata is told to be done in C Major.

C Major Scale: C4 – D – E – F – G – A – B – C5.

How to find the above C Major Scale in  K. 545.

Comment: The first movement is originally written in C Major (at least thats what wikipedia says). Do you ask why mozart wrote this in C Major?

Comment: What exactly makes you question why it's said to be in key C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sonata is said to be in C major because it is indeed in C major.
But music usually modulates to other keys, then later on returns to the "home key".

The first 8 bars of this sonata only have notes which belong to C major and the scale patterns in this section are all from the C major scale. Then in bar 9 an accidental appears so the scale is D minor and in bar 11 and 12 the section ends in G major, the dominant.

The overall main key of the movement is still said to be C major and it does eventually return to C major.